# Finding erf(sqrt(x))

Tags: differential

I am trying to show that $erf(\sqrt x)=1/\sqrt\pi$ (integral from $t$ to $0$) of $e^{-t}/\sqrt t dt$

I have used the definition of $erf(x) = 2/\sqrt\pi$ (integral from $t$ to $0$) $e^{-t^2} dt$ and used a $u$-substitution and get the answer that I'm looking for in terms of $u$ (which in my substitution is $=x^2$).  Is this right?  Is it ok that my answer is not converted back to $x$.  I'm not really experienced with the error function and am not sure if I'm missing something...

Comment: The upper limit of the integral has to be in terms of x.  This has nothing to do with the particular integrand.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly then you want to show that

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^x\frac{e^{-t}}{\sqrt{t}}\,dt=\text{erf}(\sqrt{x})$$

starting from 

$$\text{erf}(\sqrt{x})=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^{\sqrt{x}} e^{-t^2}\,dt$$

make the substitution $u=t^2$. Then, $du=2t\,dt$ and the integral becomes

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^{\sqrt{x}} \frac{e^{-u}}{\sqrt{u}}du$$

although I'm not sure what to do with the $\sqrt{x}$. According to Mathematica, the upper limit should be $x$ and not $\sqrt{x}$, so I'm not sure what I did wrong.